# Content-Security-Policy problems Google Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, content-security-policy

I've build a google cloud function that takes an input and sends it to Firestore. I'll need to call it inside a Firefox WebExtension, that I'll use on Twitter. Not the first time I'm doing this type of project but this time I'm having issues regarding the "Content-Security-Policy".

I've try to call my GC function with the GC testing tool, then with Postman, then inside a Python Script and finally inside the console of a new opened tab. All of this worked!
But it doesn't work inside my WebExtension. So I tried to call my function inside the console (Firefox) while being on twitter. It doesn't works either. I'm getting the following error message :

```
error TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. <anonymous> debugger eval code:9
```

Following by this :

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at
https://...cloudfunctions.net/...?...=... (“connect-src”).
```

When trying on Chrome, I'm getting this message of error :

```
error TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at <anonymous>:9:1

Refused to connect to 'https://....cloudfunctions.net/...?...=...'
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' blob:
```

Another interesting information I could give is that, when opening the console (in Firefox) when visiting a Twitter page, I'm getting the following warning message :

```
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src or style-src: nonce-source or hash-source specified
```

And the following error message :

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).
```

FYI : Inside the GC function, I've set headers the followings way :

```
response.headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST")
```

I've also try to add the following line, but it doesn't work :

```
response.headers.set("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src * self blob: data: gap:; style-src * self 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; object-src * 'self' blob: data: gap:; img-src * self 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; connect-src self * 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; frame-src * self blob: data: gap:;")
```

Could you guys help me that ? I'm really stuck. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Another interesting information I could give is that, when opening the
> console (in Firefox) when visiting a Twitter page, I'm getting the
> following warning message :
>
> `Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src or style-src: nonce-source or hash-source specified`

This is not a WebExtension error, it's a Twitter's CSP warning because it supports [backward browsers compatibility mode](https://csplite.com/csp198/#CSP_backward_compatibility). Just ignore it, you can't influence Twitter's CSP.

> I've also try to add the following line, but it doesn't work:
> `response.headers.set("Content-Security-Policy", "...")`

WebExtension can not publish CSP in this way, you need to use [*content_security_policy* key in the app's manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy) (`manifest.json` file). See details in [CSP in WebExtension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_Security_Policy).
The default content security policy for extensions is: `script-src 'self'; object-src 'self';` that's why `https://...cloudfunctions.net/` source is blocked. Also looks like you use some kind of inline scripts in your WexExtension, therefore you have to add `'hash-value'` to the `script-src` in the `content_security_policy` key.
  `*` The `'unsafe-inline'` token can't be used in the `content_security_policy` key.

Pls note that extensions with `'unsafe-eval'`, `'unsafe-inline'`, remote script, `blob`, or remote sources in their CSP [are not allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy#exampleNote_1) for extensions listed on addons.mozilla.org due to major security issues.

Comment: thanks @granty it's already clearer in my mind.
So, as I'm getting this error when copy/paste to the console :
"Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://us-central1-twitter-fake-accounts.cloudfunctions.net/twitterFakeAccounts?screen_name=villedurable (“connect-src”).",
I tried to add this parameters to the manifest.json "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'hash-value' https://us-central1-twitter-fake-accounts.cloudfunctions.net; object-src 'self'". But I'm still getting the same network error. I'm doing something wrong ?

Comment: `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'hash-value'; object-src 'self'; connect-src us-central1-twitter-fake-accounts.cloudfunctions.net"` because host-source is blocked in the `connect-src` directive.

Comment: ok so that means I cannot override this with any parameter ?

Comment: I do not understand what do you whish to overwrite with parameter? Why your source policy `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'hash-value' us-central1-twitter-fake-accounts.cloudfunctions.net; object-src 'self';"` could be overwritten, but the `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'hash-value'; object-src 'self'; connect-src us-central1-twitter-fake-accounts.cloudfunctions.net"` - can not? Just one directive was added and things changes?

Comment: I mean than that even with `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'hash-value' us-central1-twitter-fake-accounts.cloudfunctions.net; object-src 'self';"` I'm still getting this `error TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.`

Comment: That's because fetch requires the host-source to be allowed in the `connect-src` directive.

Comment: Well, I think this problem has been resolved. I'm having other issues now but not regarding to the CSP apparently. Many thanks @granty for these information and you're patience !! It helped a lot !!